# Clonezilla backup from a running operating system?

Tags: linux, backup

I often use Clonezilla to backup my system. I have a few different partitions on my main boot drive and have an additional disk array to which I perform the backups. Essentially, I have a EFI drive, a Linux BTRFS boot partition, and an NTFS Windows boot partition.

Clonezilla is *awesome* and does exactly what I need, but it's a bit of an inconvenience to have to shut down, plug in the USB boot drive, plug in my physical keyboard, and manually do the backup.

Is there a way to run a Clonezilla-like backup from a running Linux OS so I can backup the entire boot hard disk to a file on another drive?

Comment: Backing up a drive on which you have a running OS is going to cause all sorts of problems (e.g. locked files which can not be read since the OS is using them). There might be workarounds, but I would not trust the result as a backup. Which rather defeats your goal.

Comment: Clonezilla like most live cds contains a "collection" of linux tools, all you have to do is install those tools on a linux distro of your choice and your good to go. I believe this is what you are looking for - http://partclone.org/  As previously stated never back up the partition you are working from, it will cause all types of nasties. The only utility that I know of with the ability to back up the working partition is Disk2VHD http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx but it is a windows software and only backs up to vhd.

Comment: Since I'll be reading from the actual blocks of the underlying system, ie: actual filesystem blocks, won't I not have to worry about copying sockets and stuff like that? Since it's only reading the FS and writing the output to another hard drive altogether, shouldn't it still be safe?